# How do you use git svn?

Tags: svn, git

Please provide tips for effectively using git with svn. What are your "best practices"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create the clone, use `--prefix=svn/`. It creates nicer branch names.

Also, don't neglect the `--trunk`, `--tags`, and `--branches` arguments when doing `clone` or `init`.

Fetching is one of the more time-consuming steps, so set up a cron job to do `git svn fetch` in the background. This is safe because fetching doesn't affect any of your working branches.

( Background info on `git svn fetch`: This command is executed first whenever you do `git svn rebase`, so by doing this step ahead of time, your `git svn rebase` call will usually be faster. The `fetch` command downloads SVN commits and sticks them into special branches managed by git-svn. These branches are viewable by doing `git branch -r`, and if you did the above step, they start with "svn/". )

Make sure you know how to use `git reflog`. I've had a few occasions where `git svn dcommit` died (usually because I tried to check in something huge) and my commit seemed to be lost. In every case, the commit was easily found in the reflog.

Comment: Can you explain some more about the fetch trick? What does that do? Do you just run it over and over in the background? Having done that, how do you get the changes into your branch?

Comment: Ok, added some extra info on fetch

Answer (score 4):

Here's some that I recently learned:

1. always do `git svn rebase` before doing `git svn dcommit`
2. when you are doing `dcommit`, do it from a temporary staging branch - if you (or git) mess up, it's much easier to recover by just deleting the branch and starting over

When `svn dcommit` dies halfway through a large commit and you seem to have lost all of your history, [do this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-code-hosting/msg/baf06d4d630371c3):

> How To Recover:
>
> First, open .git/logs/HEAD
>
> Find the hash of the commit that's the
>   head of your git repo. Hopefully you
>   remember the commit message and can
>   figure it out, but it should be pretty
>   obvious
>
> Back in your now f-ed up working-dir:
>
> git reset --hard <hash from log>
>
> This gets your working dir back to
>   where it was before you did a git- svn
>   dcommit.  Then:
>
> git-svn rebase git-svn dcommit

Comment: Agree on #1, but I've never found that I've needed to do #2. `dcommit` doesn't break that often, and when it does, it's not hard to recover.

Comment: today it decided that perl would dump core halfway through - it left me with my working copy missing lots of changes

Answer (score 1):

<s>If you have a post-commit hook in your SVN repository that can reject commits, then `git svn dcommit` will stop processing commits the first time a commit is rejected, and you'll have to recover your remaining commits from the git reflog.</s>

Actually, I think the above problem was caused by my cow-orker not running `git rebase -i` correctly while trying to fix the rejected commits. But, thanks to the reflog we were able to recover everything!

Answer (score 0):

I've been blogging a bit about how to live with Subversion and Git in parallel, and I've also put up a couple of rudimentary screencasts. Gathered everything here: http://www.tfnico.com/presentations/git-and-subversion

I'll try a summary:

- Just go for it! Doesn't hurt to try it out :)
- Start off with a small Git project to learn first.
- Stick to the command-line until you master it. GUI-tools might just confuse you.
- If possible, do one-off migrations, leave SVN behind, one project at a time, starting with the small ones.
- If you do have to live with a Git and SVN together, be aware that you have to give up many advantages you get from Git, like branches, but you get the "local" benefits (stash, index, speed).
- If you are one Git user, just do git-svn rebasing and dcommitting by yourself.
- If you are several Git collaborators, set up a central Git/SVN that only pulls from SVN, while each Git-user dcommits directly back to SVN. [More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880405/can-different-git-svn-clones-of-the-same-svn-repository-expect-to-be-able-to-shar/3422422#3422422).